# Remove DIV on Click

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV which I want to be removed when I click a link contained inside that DIV. Here is what I have:

```
<div id="clients-edit-wrapper">
    <div class="close-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="close-div">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click "Close" I want `clients-edit-wrapper` to be removed. I'm looking for a way to do this by referencing the parent DIV of the Close link which, in this case, is `clients-edit-wrapper`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Answer from Huangism below:

```
$('.close-div').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

This only works if the element you would like to remove is two parents up. In my case, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Your answer will depend on if you want to delete the div in a relative manner (via parent or closest) or an absolute one (via id).

Comment: It will be in a relative manner (via parent).

Comment: Regarding the accepted answer. Use `on()` instead. `live()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. If you are using jQuery 1.6 and earlier use `delegate()` instead of `live()`. I believe the reason is mainly that `live()` exhibited memory issues. If you happen to use version 1.3 and earlier use `bind()`. `bind()` was added in 1.0, `live()` in 1.3, `delegate()` in 1.4.2 and `on()` in 1.7.

Comment: You should change the accepted answer.

Comment: To what? There isn't another answer on this page that helped me more than the one I selected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

given your html markup

Updated to .on()

```
$('.close-div').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest("#clients-edit-wrapper").remove();
});
```

More flexibility with `.closest`, this gives you the option to have more more parents or less parents.

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

**Edit**
(Added related resources)
Please see jQuery documentation on [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is **deprecated**. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

As far as I know this is due to memory concerns/issues with `live()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Huangism! I will accept as the correct answer in 5 min.

Comment: @FastTrack you should use closest as in Vision's answer, it is better logically, more flexible

Comment: Huangism: But if I were to use Vision's solution, I would have to put multiple instances of `$(this).closest("#clients-edit-wrapper").remove();` for each DIV that has a `.close-div` link.

Comment: This answer is wrong on many levels. First, don't use live. it's deprecated. Secondly, you're assuming the element to be removed is always two parents up. Lastly, this answer explicitly provides the solution from somebody else's answer, meaning the original author should get the reputation for it. I feel very strongly that this should **not** be the accepted answer.

Comment: First, I'm not using live. Second, the element to be removed will **always** be two parents up. Last, I'm using the top part of this answer which was **not** taken from someone else's answer.

Comment: @FastTrack You're not using live, but you're using the top part of the answer which itself encourages the use of live? There's a bit of confusion there. Calling parent twice means this code won't scale to cover other instances where the target is three items up, or one. It's far better to call `closest` than to call `parent` over and over since `closest` will work from any depth. Of course it has its faults too, since it assumes the target is always a parent.

Comment: All I needed was to be able to reference ANY element that is ALWAYS going to be two parents up. I don't want to have multiple instances of `closest` in my code since using `closest` would require a unique ID each time I needed it. I wanted one line, contained within a `click` function, that would reference a DIV two parents up. Huangism's answer of `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` did this perfectly.

Comment: At the very least, `parent().parent()` is just ugly, you could use `.parents().eq(1)` to grab the second parent, as `parents()` works up the DOM chain from the element. JSBin to show it working: http://jsbin.com/ovawij/edit#javascript,html

Comment: I agree `parent().parent()` is a bit ugly. I like `.parents().eq(1)`. I'm using that now.

Comment: @FastTrack So you're not using the `live` portion of this answer, and you're not using `.parent().parent()` portion. What part of this answer solved your problem now?

Comment: What do you suggest I do? Create my own answer and make that the correct one?

Answer (score 9):

Here is one solution:

```
$(".close-div").on("click", function(event) {
    $("#clients-edit-wrapper").remove();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

To get `#clients-edit-wrapper` element relatively to `.close-div` element, you can use either `parent().parent()` or `closest` with ID:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();                  // will do
$(this).closest("#clients-edit-wrapper").remove();   // the same
```

However, the last doesn't make sense, since IDs of page elements should be unique, and there won't be another `#clients-edit-wrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".close-div").click(function(){

    $("#clients-edit-wrapper").remove();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#clients-edit-wrapper').find('.close-div').click(function(){
   $('#clients-edit-wrapper').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `closest` as well.

```
$('.close-div').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#clients-edit-wrapper').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you base the element off the parent, I'd encourage event-delegation:

```
$("#clients-edit-wrapper").on("click", ".close-div", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.delegateTarget).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="clients-edit-wrapper">
    <div class="close-wrapper">
         <a href="#" onclick="$('#clients-edit-wrapper').remove();" class="close-div">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Who and why gave the guy -1? [Here is jsfiddle that shows it works the required way.](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz2JK/)  +1 from me.

Comment: I didn't vote on this answer, however the practice of blending JavaScript in with Markup is frowned upon. It makes difficult-to-manage code. Better to do all binding from the JavaScript and not from attributes like `onclick`.

Comment: Good answer. Writing code in markup is helpful in situations like these where not much needs to be accomplished.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').on('click','.close-div', function(){
  $(this).closest("#clients-edit-wrapper").remove();
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.